# Подключение формы входа/регистрации Django

Tags: django

Делаю бэкенд для шаблона на Django, есть окно для входа и регистрации

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
            <!-- Форма входа по умолчанию -->
            <form id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberMe">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="rememberMe">
                    Remember me</label>
                    <a href="forgot_password.html" class="forgot-password-link">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>

            <!-- Форма регистрации (скрыта по умолчанию) -->
            <form id="registerForm" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="country">Country *</label>
                    <input type="country" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Enter your country" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="registerPassword">Set a Password *</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPassword" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                 <div class="form-group form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="TermsConditions">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="TermsConditions" required>
                        I have read and agree to the
                    </label>
                    <a href="terms.html" class="terms-link">Terms & Conditions</a>
                    <a href="policy.html" class="policy-link" style="margin-left: 10px;">Privacy Policy</a>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Age">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Age" required>
                    I confirm that i'm of legal age
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить эту форму к Django